# Find all possible values of $z$ such that $\cos z=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{i}{4}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all possible values of $z$ such that $\cos z=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{i}{4}$.

Here is my attempt:

$\cos z=\frac{\mathit{e}^{zi}+\mathit{e}^{-zi}}{2}=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{i}{4}$

$2\mathit{e}^{zi}+2\mathit{e}^{-zi}=3+i$

$2\mathit{e}^{2zi}+2=3\mathit{e}^{zi}+i\mathit{e}^{zi}$

Rearranging and using the quadratic formula, I get:

$\mathit{e}^{zi}=\frac{3+i\pm \sqrt{-6-6i}}{4}$

The answer in the back of the textbook is $z=\pm (\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi n-i\frac{1}{2}\log 2)$. But after logging both sides of my equation and dividing each side by $i$, I do not get the same $z$. Is this because my solution is wrong or is it because I simplified wrong?

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, I guess I should've specified. Basic Complex Analysis by Marsden.

Comment: You asked for tips. When looking at complex values of $\cos z$ it is usually easier to use $\cos(x+iy)=\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve $\cos(z)=\frac 34+\frac i4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210207/solve-cosz-frac-34-frac-i4)